# Cannot Rotate JPanel Image

Tags: java, swing, graphics, rotation, jpanel

I have been having trouble rotating one of my sprites in a game I'm working on. I have followed a tutorial about rotating images on JPanels about the center of the image (which was very well-done). I even created a simple project that works just fine.

However, when I tried to use the same technique on my game, my sprite will not rotate. I have determined that the problem is drawing the sprite, as I have checked in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method via a `println()` statement that the rotation value is updated properly and that the `repaint()` method is being called when appropriate.

Here is the relevant code to the issue (excludes unnecessary methods and such):

Highest-level class:

```
public abstract class GameObject extends JPanel {

    protected BufferedImage image;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Draw sprite
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        // Clean up
        g.dispose();
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

Lowest-level class:

```
// Entity is a subclass of GameObject. 
// It does not override paintComponent.
// All it does is add an update method that is called every game tick.

public abstract class MicroObject extends Entity { 

    protected Location location; // variable to store position and rotation

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.translate(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(location.getRotation()));

        // In the following two lines, image is inherited from GameObject
        g2.translate(-image.getWidth(this) / 2, -image.getHeight(this) / 2);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        g2.dispose();
        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

I know this isn't necessarily a unique question, but I've looked at all of the "duplicate" threads, and they've all left me with similar answers, but the same problem in the end. I would appreciate it if someone took the time to look at my code and see where I went wrong.

Thank you all!

Comment: Don't dispose the Graphics object that is passed into the paintComponent() method. You only use dispose() on Graphics objects the you create. So in your case you don't need a dispose() at all since you are just casting the Graphcis parameter to a Graphics2D. If you need more help then post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr I have two comments. One, in my working program, both `g.dispose()` and `g2.dispose()` are in place, yet it works fine, but that's not really relevant. Two, when I remove `g.dispose()` in my above code, nothing changes, yet when I remove `g2.dispose()` in the above example, two images are drawn. One is the default image, the other is the rotated one. I imagine it is because I am calling `super.paintComponent(g)`. Is there a way I can avoid that and override the `GameObject` `paintComponent()` method?

Comment: @camickr Nevermind, if I delete the `super.paintComponent(g)`, it works just fine. Thank you for the suggestion to remove `g.dispose()` and `g2.dispose()`.

Comment: `but that's not really relevant.` - improper coding is always relevant. It may not be an issue is this particular example but  that Graphics object is used by other components in your application. That is why you should also never to transforms etc on that Graphics object since the transform will also be applied to other components. `if I delete the super.paintComponent(g), it works just fine.` - why do you override the paintComponent() method in your GameObject class if you expect child classes to actually do the painting?

Comment: @camickr Usually, child classes don't do the painting, but I need the `MicroObject` class to override it to do its own painting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't dispose those Graphics objects! They're re-used by Swing to draw children components & borders.

The reason why it's not working is because `GameObject` is disposing the graphics object before `MicroObject` can use it.

Also, there's no reason to draw the image twice. Remove the code in `GameObject`'s `paintComponent()`.

Lastly, just use classes. There's no reason for those to be abstract.

So:

Highest-level class:

```
public class GameObject extends JPanel {

    protected BufferedImage image;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Don't draw sprite. Subclass will do that.

        // Don't clean up. Swing does that for us.
    }
}
```

Lowest-level class:

```
// Entity is a subclass of GameObject. 
// It does not override paintComponent.
// All it does is add an update method that is called every game tick.

public class MicroObject extends Entity { 

    protected Location location; // variable to store position and rotation

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.translate(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(location.getRotation()));

        // In the following two lines, image is inherited from GameObject
        g2.translate(-image.getWidth(this) / 2, -image.getHeight(this) / 2);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of not disposing the `Graphics` object. However, I cannot remove the `GameObject` drawing method content because other subclasses of `GameObject` rely on their superclass's ability to draw images to the `JPanel`. However, by removing `super.paintComponent(g)` from the method in the `MicroObject` class, the method works as intended, albeit with the corners being cropped off because of trigonometry and squares being longer diagonally than their sides.

Comment: "because other subclasses of GameObject rely on their superclass's ability to draw images to the JPanel" No. No they don't. By removing that `super.paintComponent(g)`, you are telling java that you don't want the superclass's `paintComponent` to be used, you want to completely override `paintComponent`.

Comment: Exactly. I wanted to completely override the `paintComponent()` method. I didn't realize this was the solution until I removed it, and it all of a sudden worked. `GameObject` is not only a parent of `MicroObject`. It is also a parent of other classes in other Java projects that I use. I need a general `paintComponent()` method to save myself time and frustration from having to recode it every time I create a new subclass, but I needed to make an exception for the `MicroObject` class because I wanted to use a totally different method of drawing the component.

Comment: I didn't realize there were other subclasses, that makes sense now. Good luck with your game!

Comment: Thank you! Now that this problem is solved I've got to work out how to increase the size of my JPanel when I rotate the image.